# Organizing data in DynamoDB as list of maps

Tags: javascript, maps, amazon-dynamodb

I am pretty new to DynamoDB. I am trying to organize my database such that it looks like as below:

```
{
   userId : userID,
   phoneMap :
   [
      { 
         name: Joe,
         phone: +16712232312
  },
  {
     name: Ron,
     phone: +18972345126
  }
   ]
}
```

I am able to add data to my list called `phoneMap` using the below code:

```
EntryService.prototype.update = function (userId, name, phone, cb) {
  var phoneMapToAdd = {
    name: name,
    phone: phone
  };

  this.dynamodb.update({
    TableName: "phoneMapTable",
    Key: { "userId": userId },
    UpdateExpression: "SET #phoneMap = list_append(#phoneMap, :entry)",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#phoneMap": "phoneMap" }, 
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":entry": [phoneMapToAdd] },
  }, cb);
};
```

However, I am unable to update existing entries or delete the data from map. Also the below code does not check for duplicates. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Can you provide an error message that you have?

Comment: List doesn't check for duplicates. Only set check for duplicates (SS or NS).

Comment: Thanks @notionquest. I did a workaround. For deleting, I figure out the index which has to be deleted and use the remove expression and call update. Similarly for duplicate check I parse through the whole list and see if there is already an entry for that name, and I don't create a new one if entry already exists with the same phone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround. I searched a lot and realised that with the my DynamoDB structure I cannot simply update any contact. I need to find out the index in the list which I want to update, I then delete it and then add the updated contact as a new contact.

```js
EntryService.prototype.delete = function (userId, indx, cb) {
  var params = {
    TableName: "phoneMapTable",
    Key: {
      "userId": userId
    },
    UpdateExpression: "REMOVE phoneMap["+indx+"]",
    ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
  };
  this.dynamodb.update(params, cb);
};
```

I then add it to my already existing list like

```js
EntryService.prototype.append = function (userId, name, phone, cb) {
  var phoneMapToAdd = {
    name: name,
    phone: phone
  };
  console.log(phoneMapToAdd);
  this.dynamodb.update({
    TableName: "phoneMapTable",
    Key: { "userId": userId },
    UpdateExpression: "SET #phoneMap = list_append(#phoneMap, :entry)",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#phoneMap": "phoneMap" }, 
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":entry": [phoneMapToAdd] },
  }, cb);
};
```

This is a workaround but I could not find any other way of doing that.

Comment: Is this still the best approach?